# auto zeroing in comparator modelling

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I am trying to model comparator with offset correction using auto zeroing method. Initially I am trying to model the ideal capacitor in LTspice. Here, I charge the top plate of the capacitor using offset (7m)[image: Capacitor Modelling], and bottom plate with my required input voltage for comparison (1mv).

The wave form of the same simulation can  be seen below. Vpulse1 and vpulse 2 are same. [image: simulation result]. I am able to model the output from one end to be offset + input value. I also dont know where there is a step in between the output.

When I try to do the same with respect to ideal Opamp , I face some issue.  The same technique, I am using here as well for capacitor charging, initially by charging top plate with offset using negative feedback circuit (voltage follower), and later trying to charge the bottom plate. The issue I am facing is, the inverting terminal voltage doesn't become (Voffset + vin ), rather after feedback, the inverting terminal node voltage raises linearly giving kind of linear voltage, causing improper functioning of voltage comparator.Here, offset is 3mv and input is 2mv. I am attaching images of result of op amp circuit and simulation. How to resolve this? Even though the result is correct, meaning output must go to zero, but this doesn't raise to the desired voltage level say in our case to 5mv, as it was in previous capacitor modelling.
[image: opamp model]
[image: simulation result]

Comment: Are you using `UniversalOpamp1` or `UniversalOpamp2`?  Also, I don't know if it's intentional or relevant, but your switch models default to an ON resistance of 1Ω.

Comment: @SteKulov I am using univseralOpamp 4. I dont have issue with on resistance, my issue is why its not working the way its happening for the capacitor model.

Comment: You can't break the feedback loop like that.  Keep the feedback steady with a fixed wire, and then run a separate switched line to the capacitor.  Something more like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG2Ry.png

Comment: @SteKulov breaking of feedback is required to make it work the way intended.

Comment: OK, then I don't understand what you're trying to do and cannot help you.